# FTS in sql 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, full-text-search

Can somebody please explain how to find out if full text search is enabled in SQL 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FTS Installed At the Instance Level**

`SELECT` [`SERVERPROPERTY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx)`('IsFullTextInstalled')`

This will return 0 or 1 if full text search is installed (Instance wide).

**FTS Enabled At the Database Level**

`SELECT is_fulltext_enabled FROM` [`sys.databases`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534%28SQL.90%29.aspx) 
`WHERE database_id = DB_ID()`

This will return 0 or 1 if full text search is enabled in the current database.

Answer (score 1):

See if the SQL Server FullText Indexing service is running.

After that, you have to create a catalog for the database and then the fulltext indexes on the relevant columns.

For more information, refer to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142497(SQL.90).aspx